# Import .odc file into Excel via PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell

I created a PowerQuery in excel which gets data from an API, modifies it, and presents it in a table. I have exported the PowerQuery to a `.odc` file called `Query - Singles - Template.odc`.

I also have a PowerShell script which is dynamically creating excels where needed, as well as taking the `.odc` template, replacing the API URL and creating a new `.odc` for each excel created.

I have tried to mainly import the `.odc` into the created excels and it is working as expected. However I cant find a way to import these `.odc` files in to excel via PowerShell script.

**PowerShell Script:**

```bsh
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $False
$Excel.visible = $False
$WorkBook = $Excel.Workbooks.Add()
$WorkSheet = $WorkBook.worksheets.item(1)
$WorkSheet.name = "data"

((Get-Content -path "$Path\Query - Singles - Template.odc" -Raw) -replace "TempSetCode",$Set) | Set-Content -Path  "$Path\$Set\Query - Singles - $Set.odc"

### Code to import .odc file into excel

$WorkBook.SaveAs("$SetPath\$Set-main-$ReleaseDate.xlsx", 51) 
$WorkBook.Close($True)

$Excel.Quit()
[void][System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($WorkSheet)
[void][System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($WorkBook)
[void][System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this, not by importing the `.odc` file into excel, but by opening the `.odc` file into excel and then saving that file.

```bsh
$InFile = Get-Item("$Path\$Set\Query - Singles - $Set.odc")

$Excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $False
$Excel.visible = $False
$WorkBook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($InFile.FullName)
$WorkSheet = $WorkBook.worksheets.item(1)
$WorkSheet.name = "data"

$WorkBook.RefreshAll()

$WorkBook.SaveAs("$SetPath\$Set-main-$ReleaseDate.xlsx", 51) 
$WorkBook.Close($True)

$Excel.Quit()
[void][System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($WorkSheet)
[void][System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($WorkBook)
[void][System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```